# How to create an ID, along two columns, allowing for duplication?

Tags: r

My `data.frame` contains a log on individual workers and where they spend their time on certain wards of a hospital. The `data.frame` is structured as follows:

```
      Shift Worker          Ward    Duration
     <fctr> <fctr>         <fctr>    <dbl>
1       R1 Daniel          General    10
2       R1 Daniel          General    15 
3       R2 Daniel          Anaesth    11
4       R2 Daniel          Anaesth    13
5       R2 Daniel          Anaesth    4
6       R2 Daniel          General    15
7       R2 Daniel          General    35
8       R2 Daniel          Anaesth    6
9       R2 Daniel          Anaesth    6
10      R1 Caleb           Plastics   10
11      R1 Caleb           Plastics   9
12      R1 Caleb           Plastics   10
13      R1 Caleb           Neuro      9
14      R1 Caleb           Neuro      9
15      R1 Caleb           Plastics   10
16      R1 Caleb           Plastics   10
```

I now wish to add a column that contains a unique ID for each ward, along every worker, although I want the ID to be accumulative and allow for duplication. My anticipated output would be:

```
      Shift Worker          Ward    Duration     ID
     <fctr> <fctr>         <fctr>    <dbl>     <fctr>
1       R1 Daniel          General    10         1
2       R1 Daniel          General    15         1
3       R2 Daniel          Anaesth    11         2
4       R2 Daniel          Anaesth    13         2
5       R2 Daniel          Anaesth    4          2
6       R2 Daniel          General    15         3
7       R2 Daniel          General    35         3
8       R2 Daniel          Anaesth    6          4
9       R2 Daniel          Anaesth    6          4
10      R1 Caleb           Plastics   10         1
11      R1 Caleb           Plastics   9          1 
12      R1 Caleb           Plastics   10         1
13      R1 Caleb           Neuro      9          2
14      R1 Caleb           Neuro      9          2
15      R1 Caleb           Plastics   10         3
16      R1 Caleb           Plastics   10         3
```

Notice how the ID accumulates. How do I please do this?

The reason I want this ID is to call out the first and last entry of ward, according to each shift and worker. My anticipated output then would be:

```
      Shift Worker          Ward    Duration     ID
     <fctr> <fctr>         <fctr>    <dbl>     <fctr>
1       R1 Daniel          General    10         1
2       R1 Daniel          General    15         1
3       R2 Daniel          Anaesth    11         2
5       R2 Daniel          Anaesth    4          2
6       R2 Daniel          General    15         3
7       R2 Daniel          General    35         3
8       R2 Daniel          Anaesth    6          4
9       R2 Daniel          Anaesth    6          4
10      R1 Caleb           Plastics   10         1
12      R1 Caleb           Plastics   10         1
13      R1 Caleb           Neuro      9          2
14      R1 Caleb           Neuro      9          2
15      R1 Caleb           Plastics   10         3
16      R1 Caleb           Plastics   10         3
```

Is there a way to please do this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(Worker) %>% mutate(ID = data.table::rleid(Ward))` or in full data.table, `library(data.table); setDT(df)[, ID := rleid(Ward), by = Worker][]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this after grouping by 'Worker' by comparing the adjacent elements in 'Ward' i.e. removing the first and last and then with `cumsum` get the required output

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(Worker) %>% 
   mutate(ID = cumsum(c(TRUE, Ward[-1] != Ward[-n()])))
#   Shift Worker     Ward Duration    ID
#   <chr>  <chr>    <chr>    <int> <int>
#1     R1 Daniel  General       10     1
#2     R1 Daniel  General       15     1
#3     R2 Daniel  Anaesth       11     2
#4     R2 Daniel  Anaesth       13     2
#5     R2 Daniel  Anaesth        4     2
#6     R2 Daniel  General       15     3
#7     R2 Daniel  General       35     3
#8     R2 Daniel  Anaesth        6     4
#9     R2 Daniel  Anaesth        6     4
#10    R1  Caleb Plastics       10     1
#11    R1  Caleb Plastics        9     1
#12    R1  Caleb Plastics       10     1
#13    R1  Caleb    Neuro        9     2
#14    R1  Caleb    Neuro        9     2
#15    R1  Caleb Plastics       10     3
#16    R1  Caleb Plastics       10     3
```

---

Or a `base R` option would be to do a group by with `ave` and get the index using `rle`

```
df1$ID <- with(df1, as.integer(ave(Ward, Worker, FUN = function(x) 
                       with(rle(x), rep(seq_along(values), lengths)))))
```